# Go Active Directory OBJECTGUID attribute

Tags: go

I'm pretty new to Go and I'm creating an LDAP Extractor,

Currently having problems converting the OBJECTGUID attribute into a human readable human string to be inserted into a database later.

I'm using the `github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3` package I've tried both 
`entry.GetAttributeValue("objectGUID")` and `entry.GetRawAttributeValue("objectGUID")`

I've string `string(variable)` have tried the  `hex.DecodeString(s)`  and still getting non-readable characters.

Anyone has any idea how could i convert this into a normal ut8 string?

Comment: If the field is a UUID, then it might be returning a raw []byte instead of a string. You might want to try entry.GetRawAttributeValue(), and `fmt.Sprintf("%x",value)`. There is also a github.com/google/uuid package which you can use to parse it as UUID.

Comment: @noize were you able to get through in converting GUID to string ?

Comment: @sushanth yes i used Burak help

.html.EscapeString(fmt.Sprintf("%x", entry.GetRawAttributeValue("objectGUID")))